# Вывести json как поле mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне нужно вывести json как поле mysql, то есть допустим у меня есть такой json который хранится в значении одного из столбцов mysql

```
{
  "firstKey": 5,
  "secondKey": 10,
  "thirdKey": 15
}
```

Мне нужно вывести его как таблицу mysql, а именно

```
+----------+-----------+----------+
| firstKey | secondKey | thirdKey |
+----------+-----------+----------+
|        5 |        10 |       15 |
+----------+-----------+----------+
```

Json содержит в себе только `Map<String,Integer>`

Comment: 1) Какая версия сервера? 2) Имена полей, на момент выполнения запроса, известны?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Версия сервера 8, имена полей известны, но их много. Я просто хочу перенести эти значения в новую базу. Избавляюсь от json в таблицах

Comment: Если "размотать" JSON вертикально ещё можно (да и не очень сложно, в общем-то), то потом поверх размотанного нужен PIVOT - а с ним у MySQL, мягко говоря, вообще никак. Так что я бы рекомендовал выгрузку в CSV, конвертацию формата и обратную загрузку.

Answer (score 0):

Всегда есть вариант «в лоб»:

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.a') AS a
     , JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.b') AS b
     , JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.c') AS c
-- …
  FROM t
;
```

Пример:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tyBjKafaab6oGpxRkQXugg/0.